# Range query for a keyword or a date type field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field which store the insert time,such as `2016-10-10 11:00:00.000`,I tried `keyword` type and `date` type,they all meet the `range` requirements,such as

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "time" : {
                "gte" : "2016-10-10 11:00:00.000",
                "lte" : "2016-10-10 12:00:00.000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`keyword` and `date` type which is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, since you're storing dates, it's more appropriate to use the `date` data type, indeed. Internally, those dates will be stored as a `long` timestamps and the range query will be run on them, so that you have a **numerical range**.

`keyword` is intended to be used for string data. If you store those dates as keyword, your dates will be stored as unanalyzed strings and the range query that will be run on them will consider them as a **lexical range**.

If you ever need to create `date_histogram` aggregation out of those dates, the `keyword` type won't do it. So you should definitely prefer the `date` data type.